# How to get value from ntext (in xml format) column in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, type-conversion

I have a column in my SQL database that is called **Triggers_xml_data** and its type is **ntext**.  The column is in a **xml** format and I am trying to get a value from a certain part of the **xml**.  I seen an example of this being done without a column like this:

```
declare @fileContent xml
set @fileContent ='<my:Header>
<my:Requestor>Mehrlein, Roswitha</my:Requestor>
<my:RequestorUserName>SJM\MehrlR01</my:RequestorUserName>
<my:RequestorEmail>RMehrlein@SJM.com</my:RequestorEmail>   
<my:HRContact>Roswita  Mehrlein, Beatrice Porta</my:HRContact>
<my:Entity>SJM Germany</my:Entity>
<my:Department>HR/Administration</my:Department>
<my:PositionTitle>Sales Representative</my:PositionTitle>     
<my:JobDescription>x0lGQRQAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAeAQAyAAAAVgBAAAAA=</my:JobDescription>
<my:PositionDepartment>Sales</my:PositionDepartment>'
 
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2005-08-29T12-58-51' as my)
select @fileContent.value('(//my:PositionDepartment)[1]', 'varchar(255)')
```

But I want to select my column like this:

```
Declare @filevalue xml

select de.triggers_xml_data
from dbo.DEPLOYMENT_ENVIRONMENT as de
```

But this is not working and I tried to use this  `@filecontent.value('(//value)[1]','varchar(255)')` and making it equal the column value, I have tried casting it but I can't find a way to do this.  Is this possible?

When I do this:

```
SELECT 
CAST(
    REPLACE(CAST(de.TRIGGERS_XML_DATA AS VARCHAR(MAX)), 'encoding="utf-16"', '')
  AS XML).value('(triggers/triggerDefinition/config/item/value)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(max)') as Item, de.ENVIRONMENT_ID
from dbo.DEPLOYMENT_ENVIRONMENT as de
where de.ENVIRONMENT_ID = 19234819
```

I am getting a null value returned.

Here is an example of what my xml could look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<configuration xml:space="preserve">

<triggers>
    <defined>true</defined>
    <triggerDefinition>
      <id>1</id>
      <name>After successful deployment</name>
      <userDescription/>
      <isEnabled>true</isEnabled>
      <pluginKey>com.atlassian.bamboo.triggers.atlassian-bamboo-triggers:afterSuccessfulDeployment</pluginKey>
      <triggeringRepositories/>
      <config>
        <item>
          <key>deployment.trigger.afterSuccessfulDeployment.triggeringEnvironmentId</key>
          <value>19234819</value>
        </item>
      </config>
    </triggerDefinition>
  </triggers>
  <bambooDelimiterParsingDisabled>true</bambooDelimiterParsingDisabled>
</configuration>
```

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx) - and if you have  **XML** data, then you should **really** use the `XML` datatype - that what's it there for!

Comment: @marc_s I agree but this database was created by bamboo so I didn't choose the types just had to use them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The XML, as you posted it, is not valid. Your code example does not work... It is not allowed to use a namespace prefix without a namespace declaration. Furthermore your example misses the closing `Header`-tag...

I corrected this...

```
DECLARE @yourTbl TABLE(ID INT, YourXML NTEXT);
INSERT INTO @yourTbl VALUES
(1,N'<my:Header xmlns:my="DummyUrl">
<my:Requestor>Mehrlein, Roswitha</my:Requestor>
<my:RequestorUserName>SJM\MehrlR01</my:RequestorUserName>
<my:RequestorEmail>RMehrlein@SJM.com</my:RequestorEmail>   
<my:HRContact>Roswita  Mehrlein, Beatrice Porta</my:HRContact>
<my:Entity>SJM Germany</my:Entity>
<my:Department>HR/Administration</my:Department>
<my:PositionTitle>Sales Representative</my:PositionTitle>     
<my:JobDescription>x0lGQRQAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAeAQAyAAAAVgBAAAAA=</my:JobDescription>
<my:PositionDepartment>Sales</my:PositionDepartment>
</my:Header>');

--Lazy approach
SELECT ID
      ,CAST(CAST(YourXml AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS XML).value(N'(//*:PositionDepartment)[1]','nvarchar(max)')
FROM @yourTbl;


--explicit approach
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('DummyUrl' AS my)
SELECT ID
      ,CAST(CAST(YourXml AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS XML).value(N'(/my:Header/my:PositionDepartment)[1]','nvarchar(max)')
FROM @yourTbl
```

### Some Background

If possible you **should not store XML in other format than `XML`** and further more one **should avoid `NTEXT`, as it is depricated since SS2005!**.

You have to cast `NTEXT` to `NVARCHAR(MAX)` first, than cast this to `XML`. The second will break, if the XML is not valid. That means: **If the XML is really the way you posted it, this cannot work!**

### UPDATE: String-based approach, if XML does not work

If you cannot cast this to XML you might try this

```
--String based
WITH Casted AS
(
    SELECT ID
          ,CAST(YourXML AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS TheXmlAsString
    FROM @yourTbl
)
,WithPosition AS
(
    SELECT Casted.*
          ,CHARINDEX(N'<my:PositionDepartment>',TheXmlAsString) + LEN(N'<my:PositionDepartment>') AS FirstLetter
    FROM Casted
)
SELECT ID 
      ,SUBSTRING(TheXmlAsString,FirstLetter,CHARINDEX('<',TheXmlAsString,FirstLetter)-FirstLetter)
FROM WithPosition
```

### UPDATE 2

According to your edit the following returns a `NULL` value. This is good, because it shows, that the cast was successfull.

> ```
> SELECT 
> CAST(
>     REPLACE(CAST(de.TRIGGERS_XML_DATA AS VARCHAR(MAX)), 'encoding="utf-16"', '')
>   AS XML).value('(triggers/triggerDefinition/config/item/value)[1]',
> 'NVARCHAR(max)') as Item, de.ENVIRONMENT_ID
> from dbo.DEPLOYMENT_ENVIRONMENT as de
> where de.ENVIRONMENT_ID = 19234819
> ```

Try this (skip namespace with wildcard):

```
SELECT 
CAST(
    REPLACE(CAST(de.TRIGGERS_XML_DATA AS VARCHAR(MAX)), 'encoding="utf-16"', '')
  AS XML).value('(*:triggers/*:triggerDefinition/*:config/*:item/*:value)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(max)') as Item, de.ENVIRONMENT_ID
from dbo.DEPLOYMENT_ENVIRONMENT as de
where de.ENVIRONMENT_ID = 19234819
```

And this should be even better:

```
SELECT 
CAST(CAST(de.TRIGGERS_XML_DATA AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS XML).value('(*:triggers/*:triggerDefinition/*:config/*:item/*:value)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(max)') as Item, de.ENVIRONMENT_ID
from dbo.DEPLOYMENT_ENVIRONMENT as de
where de.ENVIRONMENT_ID = 19234819
```

### UPDATE 3

I'd rather cut away the full declaration. Your posted example would go like this

```
DECLARE @DEPLOYMENT_ENVIRONMENT TABLE(ENVIRONMENT_ID INT, TRIGGERS_XML_DATA NTEXT);
INSERT INTO @DEPLOYMENT_ENVIRONMENT VALUES
(19234819,N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<configuration xml:space="preserve">

<triggers>
    <defined>true</defined>
    <triggerDefinition>
      <id>1</id>
      <name>After successful deployment</name>
      <userDescription/>
      <isEnabled>true</isEnabled>
      <pluginKey>com.atlassian.bamboo.triggers.atlassian-bamboo-triggers:afterSuccessfulDeployment</pluginKey>
      <triggeringRepositories/>
      <config>
        <item>
          <key>deployment.trigger.afterSuccessfulDeployment.triggeringEnvironmentId</key>
          <value>19234819</value>
        </item>
      </config>
    </triggerDefinition>
  </triggers>
  <bambooDelimiterParsingDisabled>true</bambooDelimiterParsingDisabled>
</configuration>');

WITH Casted AS
(
    SELECT CAST(de.TRIGGERS_XML_DATA AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS XmlAsSting
    FROM @DEPLOYMENT_ENVIRONMENT as de
    where de.ENVIRONMENT_ID = 19234819
)
SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(XmlAsSting,CHARINDEX('?>',XmlAsSting)+2,8000) AS XML).value('(/*:configuration/*:triggers/*:triggerDefinition/*:config/*:item/*:value)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(max)') as Item
FROM Casted;
```

Comment: @Shungo that wasn't my xml it was an example I seen mine is a large amount in the column called trigger_xml_data, that is the problem I am having

Comment: So I want to make the xml my column in the table but I get errors when trying to do so

Comment: @GuinnessIsLife, How should one help you, without knowing the actual XML? You should **try to reduce the real** XML without changing the relevant structure**. Btw: If `<my:PositionDepartment>` does not occur multiple times, the *lazy approach* should work fine...

Comment: @GuinnessIsLife Just try `select CAST(CAST(de.triggers_xml_data AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS XML) from dbo.DEPLOYMENT_ENVIRONMENT as de`. This should return XML - as long as it is valid...

Comment: I fixed that error but now I get a null value when I do this `SELECT 
  CAST(
    REPLACE(CAST(de.TRIGGERS_XML_DATA AS VARCHAR(MAX)), 'encoding="utf-16"', '')
  AS XML).value('(triggers/triggerDefinition/config/item/value)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(max)') as Item, de.ENVIRONMENT_ID
from dbo.DEPLOYMENT_ENVIRONMENT as de
where de.ENVIRONMENT_ID = 19234819`

Comment: @GuinnessIsLife If your XML includes the encoding with as `encoding="utf-16"` this should be fine, but you **must use `NVARCHAR`** to keep this in `unicode`... This should work without the `REPLACE()`

Comment: @GuinnessIsLife See my UPDATE 2

Comment: @shungo no im still getting the null, i found an xml data that was small enough to add to the question will add it, let me know if i'm doing something wrong